# Change tkinter menu when a USB device is plugged in or taken out

Tags: python, tkinter, menu

I have a tkinter menu / menubar (NOT an OptionsMenu!)  with main 'header' category called 'Donations'. I want it so that when this **main category** has a mouse 'Enter' event happen over it, or, when the header is actually mouse-clicked upon, then a function will run. Part of the function should clear out any ***old** 'items' in this 'Donations' category, and proceed to give a refreshed set of menu items in the 'Donations' category from which a user can then happily select one of the newly refreshed items.

Setting the initial items within Donations and repopulating them later is not the problem, but the  or clicking on the main category to make the function run and CLEARING out the old items is my problem.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x220")

def foo():
    pass

def clear_and_repopulate():
    pass

menubar = tk.Menu(root)

# donations
donations_list = ["$1", "$2", "$3"]
donation_menu_item = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
# When mouse 'Enter'  OR
# donation_menu_item  header category clicked,
# then run function "clear_and_repopulate"

menubar.add_cascade(label="Donations", menu=donation_menu_item) # Shows the caption
for donation in donations_list: donation_menu_item.add_command(label=donation, command = foo())

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Appreciative of any guidance/help here. Tq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a menu, you can specify a `postcommand`, which is a command that will be called immediately before the menu is posted. Within that function you can delete all of the items and add new items.

Here's a contrived example that updates the menu with a random number of items each time you click on it:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()

menubar = tk.Menu(root)
root.configure(menu=menubar)

def update_donations_menu():
    donations_menu.delete(0, "end")

    for i in range(random.randint(1, 6)):
        donations_menu.add_command(label=f"${i}.00")

donations_menu = tk.Menu(menubar, postcommand=update_donations_menu)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Donations", menu=donations_menu)

tk.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot #1]

[image: screenshot #2]

Comment: Thanks for that Bryan. It works as is, but it seems to negate other code that I had which returned the value/name of the sub-menu item that was clicked upon.

Comment: @Micklos: I don't see how this affects that at all. You can still make the menu items do anything you want.

Comment: Indeed. My bad! I had modified other code (with an error) before applying your solution, and I forgot to unmodify it afterwards.
It is a fantastic feeling seeing it work... thank you so much!  How did you get to learn this? I checked out many references (most of which kept covering the same basics) and there is previous little on this level of tkinter control and even less with good explanations.
Thanks one more.

Comment: @Micklos: how did I get to learn this? By reading the documentation. The opening paragraphs of the [official tkinter documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) provides links to the canonical tcl/tk documentation.